# Problem when creating a dynamic table in JS. The numbers are presented separately

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble creating a dynamic table in JavaScript. The numbers are presented separately, despite being presented as a sum in the console.
I create a program that counts reports per category fetched from a specific website that I do not mention here. Thank you in advance!

```
fetch('The websites url')
.then(function (response) {
return response.json()
})
.then(function (result) {

var reports = result.requests[0].request
let reportsPerCategory = {}
for (let i = 0; i < reports.length; i++) {
  var category = result.requests[0].request[i].service_code

  if(reportsPerCategory[category] === undefined){
    reportsPerCategory[category] = 1
    var tr3 = document.createElement("tr")
    document.getElementById("table2").appendChild(tr3)
    tr3.textContent = category
    var td8 = document.createElement("td")
    tr3.appendChild(td8)

}else {
  td8.textContent = reportsPerCategory[category]++
//The result in the table cells isn't a sum of eacy category repeat
}

}
//Logs each category with the sum of repeats correctly in an array
console.log(Object.entries(reportsPerCategory))
})
.catch(function(error) {
 console.error(error)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If `reportsPerCategory[category]` already exists, you increase the count and set its result to `td8`. That however is *not* the element containing the count of that category, but the element containing the count of the *previous* iteration. To resolve that you have to also create a map of elements:

```
 var td8s = {};
```

then when you create a new `td8` store it:

```
 td8s[category] = td8;
```

and in the `else {` branch retrieve it with

```
 td8s[category].textContent = /*...*/
```

or you just generate the table after counting.

Comment: Alright! Now I get it! Thanks a lot for your help :)